# Keen-slider doesn't work well with Server-side render on the first render - NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, slider

I am using **nextJS** with typescript and got 1 error when using the **keen-slider library v5.4.0**.
The error occurs when the keen-slider is rendered for the **first time**, the items are not of the same type transform when I drag the slider. It causes items to be stacked on top of each other.
Has anyone come across such a case? Please let me know anything that can fix it.
Thank you all.

Comment: Hi, have you tried updating Keen-slider? current version is 6.6.14

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated to the latest version of keen-slider(6.6.14) and it is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the above by upgrading to keen-slider **version 6.6.14**.

```
npm i keen-slider@v6.6.14
```

And add this code below

```
const [internalSliderRef, internalSlider] = useKeenSlider(sliderOptions);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    internalSlider.current?.update({
      ...sliderOptions
    });
  }, [internalSlider, sliderOptions]);
```

Thank for all